# Bash like management in windows environment

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file

I have worked in bash on linux for a couple of years. Recently I moved to windows. In bash, I could run a couple of `.cpp` files, take output from one and give it to another in a very smooth way. However I want to do the same with `.bat` files too, but I could find no tutorial on that. Please guide me through the process.

Comment: Why not using `bash`? :) https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, you can accept it by clicking the pipe icon on its left side. It is a big reward to the answerer.

Comment: if I write in bash (cygwin), will it make portable script to other systems that don't use cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOS, written by Microsoft who were Unix heads, has syntax similar to Unix. It is the first thing they added to DOS when they bought it.

```
&    separates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatenate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% an inbuilt or user-set environment variable

!variablename! a user-set environment variable expanded at execution time, turned with command SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batch file's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```

Also, as Windows runs Unix (different flavours, depending on version. Current ones come with the Korn shell at least, but NOT `Bash`). Depending on the Windows version and edition, it is either on the DVD or has to be downloaded from MS. First, look in Windows Programs and Features in Control Panel to turn on. Else, http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx%3Fid%3D274&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=KgY8VaGtC4W1mAWVqoCQCQ&ved=0CB8QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEpycuKGGDSnWw8_RExMybUkITv3Q

Windows NT is an OS that runs other OSs. Windows, OS/2 2.1, and several POSIX/Unix implementations.

Comment: On NT-based systems there is no more dos. The dos interrupts cause only page violation. cmd.exe, the successor of command.com, is a native win32 (win64) app. There are only emulators for dos.

Comment: I didn't mention dos, I said Windows, OS/2 (up till NT4), and unix/posix. And NT does have Dos 5.5 but that is an Win32 emulator not a seperate OS which is why I didn't mention it. But our command line synax come from the unix programmers at MS when they released Dos ver 2

Comment: You mention DOS twice, which in itself isn't a problem, had you also mentioned that an _extended_ version of  the DOS batch language (though with different technological underpinning) is still in use on today's NT-based Windows platforms (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). Your syntax overview is helpful for someone who wants to learn how to create _batch files_, but not to someone looking to use  `bash` techniques and existing Unix shell scripts. Someone truly looking to switch to Windows-native technologies comparable in power to `bash` and Unix utilities should consider PowerShell.

Comment: Since you mention inbuilt variables only with respect to `%variablename%`, and not  `!variablename!`: either form can access any variable, whether predefined or user-defined, the difference is only in _when_ they are expanded (as you state).

Comment: As for running POSIX/Unix _as an OS_: ["Windows Services for Unix and Subsystem for Unix-based Applications _provide header files and libraries that make it easier to recompile or port Unix applications for use on Windows_; they _do not make Unix binaries compatible with Windows binaries_."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX). The POSIX layer was called SFU (Windows Service for Unix) up to Windows Server 2003 (the one you link to), then SUA (Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications) and is now **deprecated** and **removed from Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2**.

Comment: I did mention `!var!`. And said howto use it.  As MS dumped unix decades ago we can assume WinNT is beter. The _extended version of dos_ is Dos 5 compatible. Windows has 5 script languages. Dos proceduralm CMD hack of Dos, VBS, JScript, and the abomination powershell.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned `!var!`, but since its description only referenced "user-set", in contrast with "inbuilt or user-set" for `%var%`, I wanted to make clear that `!var!` can reference "inbuilt" variables as well. Please note that if you want others to be notified of follow-up comments, you'll have to @<name> mention them.

Comment: What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: Guys, guys, calm down... Look, I need this to happen.
I need to create a directory, it has two executables, when clicked on first one, it takes me through a couple of message boxes, takes input in next window, gives the input to the second executable and runs it. After the second one terminates, it takes output from it and displays result in another message box. 

I know it's messed up but my point is that, it can be done in bash on linux. I can replace first executable with a script. Now I don't know how to do that in Win environment.

Comment: @Trigger, I think I am being very specific about my problem. More specifically second executable is output created by a cpp file. The two executables must be portable. Better yet, if somehow I can make the whole functionality with one .exe file, I will be deeply indebted to you.

Comment: Try reading your question. There is no detail apart from wanting "batch".

Comment: Sorry, I hope I made it clear in above two comments of mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use exactly bash in windows. It is part of the [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com) distribution.

There is also [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which tries to be a minimalistic Cygwin. In my opinion it is currently nearly as big, and has major problems - with the single exception of its integrated terminal emulator named [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/).

As an alternative, if you want native technologies, you can use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). But it requires a lot of accomodation, most bash functionality is not trivial with it.

In similar situations I normally use cygwin64 with mintty (AFAIK it is included in cygwin as well).

Comment: Nice overview; if you only want `bash` + utilities, MinGW's companion product MSYS is sufficient: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS